# STAThreadAttributeを付けない方がいいのはどんなアプリケーション？

Tags: .net, com

.NETでForms/WPFを使う場合にお約束のように付けられている `STAThreadAttribute` ですが、クリップボードを扱う場合などはコンソールアプリでも付ける必要があります。

では逆に、`STAThreadAttribute` を付けない方がいい場合はあるのでしょうか。

COMサーバを作る場合であれば、MTAの方が複数スレッドから呼び出せることでパフォーマンス向上が狙えるかと思いますが、そうでないアプリケーションでMTAにする理由はあまりないように思えます。.NET内部でCOMサーバーになっているケースもあるとは思いますが、それが前述の `STAThreadAttribute` が必要な場面だとすると、結局STAにせざるを得ません。

だとするとコンソールアプリケーションやサーバー等を作る場合でも、とりあえず `STAThreadAttribute` を付けておけばいいのでは？と思ったのですがどうでしょうか。

参考サイト

- [STAとMTA - EthernalWindows](http://eternalwindows.jp/com/apartment/apartment01.html)
- [アパートメントモデルと、.NETのSTAThreadAttribute - Bug Catharsis](http://zecl.hatenablog.com/entry/20070708/p1)
- [STAThreadの意味は？: .NET Tips: C#, VB.NET](http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/form/stathread.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[STA; Single-Threaded Apartments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680112(v=vs.85).aspx)はあまり知られてはいませんが

> Each single-threaded apartment **must have a message loop** to handle calls from other processes and apartments within the same process. Single-threaded apartments without objects (client only) also **need a message loop** to dispatch the broadcast messages that some applications use.

とあり、単にスレッドをSTAで初期化すればいいというわけではなく状況によってはメッセージループを回す必要があります。
ですので、.NET Frameworkとしても確実にメッセージループを回すWinFormsやWPFのようなプロジェクトでなければ、`[STAThread]`が付与されずMTAで初期化するようにしているのだと思います。